# Is RazorEngine free?

Tags: licensing, razorengine

I would like to use [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) in a production solution we're building for a client. Can someone tell me if RazorEngine is 100% free to use i.e. no hidden costs, no licence issues if we give the solution to a client?

Edit:

Many thanks for the responses. I feel more confident that we can indeed use RazorEngine in our production code.

Is there a way I can change this question to be a wiki? I feel that all of the answers given so far are valid. Choosing just one as the accepted might be a bit unfair.

Comment: Then close your eyes and let your heart decide! :) Or mark the first posted as answer. (sometimes unfair)

Comment: if you edit it 10 times, a question becomes wiki - see [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: I've accepted an answer. My reason was the excellent Wikipedia link which tells me 100% that I can use RazorEngine for production code.

Comment: Cool. The main drive is to help each other, not only up-votes. Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and product pricing, not programming or software development. See the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [project page](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/license), they use the [Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL).

So it will be 100% free to use if you distribute compiled code to the client - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_source#Microsoft_Public_License_.28Ms-PL.29

It looks like you can distribute source code as well, as long as you include the license terms and release your whole project under this license:

> (D) If you distribute any portion of the software in source code form, you may do so only under this license by including a complete copy of this license with your distribution. If you distribute any portion of the software in compiled or object code form, you may only do so under a license that complies with this license.

Comment: I spent a little while putting a an exciting addin for visual studio  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5ymN81qf8azlwVnXaXutyg/videos (not yet available but stable). The license maintains that you need to provide it when deployed. I don't see any other restrictions unless you want to patent some part of the codebase. I have been using it for my current contract job with good results.

Answer (score 0):

It's under MS-PL license. Read more at:  http://razorengine.codeplex.com/license and http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL
In simple words, if you use razor, its source code does not have to be distributed, but it does have to be available. Well, The source code is readily available via the web.

Comment: Ahh OK. So if we built the client's ASP NET MVC website, which they have paid for, and we use RazorEngine - then as long as the source code for RazorEngine is available, then we're OK?

Comment: Yes. you should release the compiled code. (Which is what you do if you're gonna sell them your project). So no worries AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

The [license](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/license) indicates "yes".

> (A) Copyright Grant- Subject to the terms of this license, including the license conditions and limitations in section 3, each contributor grants you a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free copyright license to reproduce its contribution, prepare derivative works of its contribution, and distribute its contribution or any derivative works that you create.
>
> (B) Patent Grant- Subject to the terms of this license, including the license conditions and limitations in section 3, each contributor grants you a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license under its licensed patents to make, have made, use, sell, offer for sale, import, and/or otherwise dispose of its contribution in the software or derivative works of the contribution in the software.

Make sure you read the entire license, there are some restrictions in section three.

Just as a reminder, StackOverflow is not an authority on legal issues. These issues should be addressed to your/your company's legal council. I can't ensure my understanding of the license is correct.